# Store an ArrayList into a csv with the rows being every two elements

Tags: java, arrays, csv, arraylist

I have the following array in form of ArrayList in Java:

[a, b, c, d, e, f, ...]

I want to create a csv table with the following contents i.e. rows created with two cells every two elements:

[image]

For now that is what I have:

```js
public static void writeExcel(ArrayList<String> arrayList) throws Exception {

        BufferedWriter writer = null;

        try {

            writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("src/Orders.csv"), "utf-8"));

            for (code....)
                 
            writer.write(code ...)

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            
        } finally {

            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }


    }
```

Can somebody help me with the for loops?

Comment: Sorry, that's the edited version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following loop will work:

```
List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList.add("a");
arrayList.add("b");
arrayList.add("c");
arrayList.add("d");

int i = 0, size = arrayList.size();
while (i < size)
{
    String col1 = arrayList.get(i);
    String col2 = ",";
    i++;
    if (i < size)
    {
        col2 += arrayList.get(i);
    }

    writer.write(col1 + col2);

    // put a new line here
    writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

    i++; // go to the next one
}
```

Comment: It is String indeed. But the size of the array changes... I cannot just add manually a,b,c,d etc...

Comment: I just did that for showing an example. The code will work for any ArrayList

Comment: Edited my question again. Sorry my bad for not getting the message across.

Comment: You can just copy my loop into your method and it will work. I will even update my answer to name my list arrayList.